# Cat content of files to .txt files with common pattern name in bash

Tags: bash, loops, text, cat

I have a series of .dat files and a series of .txt files that have a common matching pattern. I want to cat the content of the .dat files into each respective .txt file with the matching pattern in the file name, in a loop. Example files are:

```
xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
xfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
xfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
#
yfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
yfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
yfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
#
pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
```

What I have tried so far is the following (I am trying to cat the content of all files starting with "xfile" to the respective model .txt file.

```
#
find -name 'xfile*' | sed 's/_mergetime_.*//' | sort -u | while read -r pattern
    do  
        echo "${pattern}"*
        cat "${pattern}"* >> "${pattern}".txt   
    done
```

Comment: so you want the `WRF`, `GFDL`, `RCA` of `xfile` all catted to like `xfile.txt`?

Comment: I want the file **xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat** catted into **pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt**

Comment: There are more than `pr_WRF` file, do you want both the `xfile` and `yfile` concatted to the `pr_WRF.txt` file ?

Comment: Yes, basically, I want a loop which will cat all files starting with "x" into the .txt file of the respective model.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your specific requirements more clearly.

Comment: You asks questions on the network, but never mark answers as accepted. Can you please take the time to review all the answers to your questions from all over the stack network and mark your accepted answers?

Answer (score 1):

Let me make some assumptions:

- All filenames contain `_mergetime_*` substring.
- The `pattern` is the portion such as `pr_GFDL` and is essential to
  identify the file.

Then would you try the following:

```
declare -A map                  # create an associative array
for f in xfile_*.dat; do        # loop over xfile_* files
    pattern=${f%_mergetime_*}   # remove _mergetime_* substring to extract pattern
    pattern=${pattern#xfile_}   # remove xfile_ prefix
    map[$pattern]=$f            # associate the pattern with the filename
done

for f in *.txt; do              # loop over *.txt files
    pattern=${f%_mergetime_*}   # extract the pattern
    [[ -f ${map[$pattern]} ]] && cat "${map[$pattern]}" >> "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want the following:

```
- xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
- yfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
----> pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt

- xfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
- yfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
----> pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA_final.txt

- xfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
- yfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
----> pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
```

So here's what you want to do in the script:

1. Get all `.nc.dat` files in the directory
2. Extra the `pr_TYPE_mergetime_region` from the file
3. Append the `_final.txt` part to the output file
4. Then actually pipe the `cat` output onto that file

So I ended up with the following code:

```sh
find *.dat | while read -r pattern
do
    output=$(echo $pattern | sed -e 's![^(pr)]*!!' -e 's!.nc.dat!!')

    cat $pattern >> "${output}_final.txt"
done
```

And here are the files I ended up with:

```
pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
```

> Kindly let me know in the comments if I misunderstood anything or missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you asks for:

`concatxy.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# do not return the pattern if no file matches
shopt -s nullglob

# Iterate all xfiles
for xfile in "xfile_pr_"*".nc.dat"; do

  # Regex to extract the common filename part
  [[ "$xfile" =~ ^xfile_(.*)\.nc\.dat$ ]]

  # Compose the matching yfile name
  yfile="yfile_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.nc.dat"

  # Compose the output text file name
  txtfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_final.txt"

  # Perform the concatenation of xfile and yfile into the .txt file
  cat "$xfile" "$yfile" >"$txtfile"
done
```

Creating populated test files:

`preptest.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Populating test files
echo "Content of xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat" >xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
echo "Content of xfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat" >xfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
echo "Content of xfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat" >xfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
#
echo "Content of yfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat" > yfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
echo "Content of yfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat" >yfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
echo "Content of yfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat" >yfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
#
#pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
#pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
#pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
```

Running test

```sh
$ bash ./preptest.sh
$ bash ./concatxy.sh
$ ls -tr1
concatxy.sh
preptest.sh
yfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
yfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
yfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
xfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
xfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
$ cat pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
Content of xfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
Content of yfile_pr_GFDL_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
$ cat pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
Content of xfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
Content of yfile_pr_WRF_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
$ cat pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA_final.txt
Content of xfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
Content of yfile_pr_RCA_mergetime_regionA.nc.dat
```